# Scheduling C# app throughts Webclient exception

Tags: c#, webclient, scheduling

I have developed a c# application to download a zip file from a site, when manually run the app, it does its job normally and exits, But when i schedule it to run automatically using task scheduler in Windows, it throws web client exception error. Please help me regarding this

The part of code for downloading the file is

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();                
wc.DownloadFile(<site>, "feed.zip");
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("extract.bat");
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new Process();
pinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pinfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
process.StartInfo = pinfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The batch file extracts the zip file.

Comment: But whats the exception / callstack? How about showing some code?

Comment: The exception thrown is " An Error Occurred during a webclient request"

Comment: Post the exception and some code is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I see these possible problems:

- If you run your application `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` could result in a different path.  `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will be set to your `bin`-folder, but in your production environment, it can point every, depending how your process is executed (for example: if you create a shortcut on your desktop, you can also modify the `Start in`-folder.
- If your current directory is configured wrong, the application would also not be able to find `extract.bat`.
- While you are debugging you have some rights on your outputfolder. But when your application is executed as a batch process, it runs under a different account. Does this account have to rights to write to your output folder?
- The website your are accessing might require a valid account. You possibly have a valid account. But the account your application  is running from in production, might not be valid account for that website.
- You are possibly behind a proxy. Perhaps you need to configure some extra settings for getting past that proxy. In your account, these settings are configured inside Internet Explorer. Perhaps the production account does not have these settings configured.